# How to call service's OnDestroy() or OnTaskRemoved() method

Tags: android, service, background-service, foreground-service

I have an issue to use service.

I am trying to use background service with permanently running. I have implemented with `AlarmManager`. So when app closed then send broadcast in service's `OnDestroy()` method. And in alarm receiver, can start service.

```
 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
 {

    serviceInstance = this;
    callHelper = new CallHelper(this);

    callHelper.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}    

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("1111111111", "stop service");
    super.onDestroy();
    setAlarmTimer();
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.d("1111111111", "stop remove");
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}

protected void setAlarmTimer() {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,intent,0);

    AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
}
```

But if I remove(swipe) the app from recent app list, then service's OnDestroy() or OnTaskRemoved doesn't called. So can't call AlarmManager.

Following is my Manifest.xml:

```
<service
    android:name=".service.CallTrackService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

How to call service's `OnDestory()` or `OnTaskRemoved()` method when removing the app from recent app list?

Anyone who know this issue then please provide a solution.

Comment: Have you found an adequate solution?  I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Service class has an `onTaskRemoved()` method which is triggered when the app is removed from the recent apps.

There the Service can call `stopSelf()` to shut itself down.

As in:

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    stopSelf();
}
```

**edit**

in android Oreo , start your service this way :

```
startForegroundService(new Intent(context, your_service.class));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I knew your answer. But doesn't called onTaskRemoved() method when remove app from recent apps in android 8.0. Please advance me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You don't.  The framework does.  A bound service is destroyed when nothing is bound to it anymore.  A started service is destroyed when its explicitly stopped, or when the system needs resources.  To explicitly stop a service, call stopService from any Context, or stopSelf from the Service.

But "I am trying to use background service with permanently running.". Not possible in modern Android.  The system will clean you up for resources.  There is no way to make it permanently run, or even pseudo permanently with gaps via an alarm.  Whatever it is you want your service to actually do, you need to find another way.

Comment: Hi Gabe. Thanks for your comment. If can't execute service permanently then I have a question. Then how can make service running always? Such as whatsapp, skype can execute service always. Even though close app and remove app from recent list. I really can't understand. Please advance me the issues that I have mistakes. Thanks

Comment: @WaterFlower No, they don't have services that always run.  They register for events from the OS, like FCM messages, and are started up when one is received.  That's not the same as an always running service.

Comment: One can use a Partial Wake Lock, as well as a JobScheduler to keep the foreground service running and prevent it from being killed by the OS.